# Vetical alignment of elements in ul > li > a > img

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html menu looks like (I use bootstrap)

[image: menu]

The code:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="thumbnails" style="text-align: center">
<li class="">
<a href="path" target="_blank" class="thumbnail" style="vertical-align: middle; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; background: #ffffff;">
<img src="money.png" alt="trigstopfactor" width="120" height="150" />descr</a>
</li>
```

I need to have all thumbnail elements have the same height and make the text content (or text and image) aligned vertically at the middle of thumbnail. I tried a lot css options, no result

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a pen of the same with the same html and following css:

Try this: [PEN](http://codepen.io/shreya1289/pen/zGxJvL)

```
    ul {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style:none;
     overflow:hidden;
    }
    ul.thumbnails li {
     float:left;
     border:1px solid red;
   }
   ul.thumbnails li img {
     vertical-align:middle;
     display:block;
     border:1px solid black;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Out This code Copy and Paste it or click here http://www.bootply.com/ROQKyZOwEm

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="125x125">
              <div class="caption">
     <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
  </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="125x125">
                   <div class="caption">
     <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
  </div>

        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="125x125">
                   <div class="caption">
     <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
  </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="125x125">
                   <div class="caption">
     <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
  </div>
        </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you but still doesn't(

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal align normally will work using `margin: 0 auto`

on top of that I found this quite useful in the past using the transform property..

http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: did you mean horizontal or vertical? i think `margin: 0 auto` just centers (horizontally)

Comment: @theatlasroom Yes as I said that is just for horizontal alignment, on top of that I have also included a link to a website that shows how to vertical align with the transform property.

Answer (score 1):

try as following:

http://jsfiddle.net/hh7bLvpv/1/

**OK EDIT** Way better solution in my opinion:

check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hh7bLvpv/2/

**UPDATED VERSION** here you get your image blown up and centered, no matter the height / size of the image: (please pay attention to the newly added containers and classes around `img`)

```
.img--container {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fullwidth {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**STANDARD VERSION**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    background: #ffffff;
}

.img {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}

ul:after {
  display:block;
  content: "";
  clear:both;
}

ul li {
  float:left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

ul li span {
  align-self: flex-end; 
    width: 100%; 
}

.thumbnail {
vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: -webkit-flex!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 120px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="thumbnails" style="text-align: center">
<li class="">
<a href="path" target="_blank" class="thumbnail" style="vertical-align: middle; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; background: #ffffff;">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x168/000/fff" alt="trigstopfactor" width="120" height="150" /><span>descr</span></a>
</li>
  
  <li class="">
<a href="path" target="_blank" class="thumbnail" style="vertical-align: middle; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; background: #ffffff;">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x168/000/fff" alt="trigstopfactor" width="120" height="150" /><span>descr</span></a>
</li>
  
    <li class="">
<a href="path" target="_blank" class="thumbnail" style="vertical-align: middle; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; background: #ffffff;">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x168/000/fff" alt="trigstopfactor" width="120" height="150" /><span>descr</span></a>
</li>
  
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet i've used, it relies on [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) though:

```
  height:100%;

  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -ms-flex-align:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

  align-items:center;
```